# List item layout views show hide

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

In list item there are two buttons buton1 and button2. 
On button1 click i want to show button2 of that row only.
This was achieved by setting button2's instance as button1's tag and then on button1's onClickListener getting button1 using getTag and changing its visibility.
Q1: Is there a more optimum method of doing this? 
Q2: On  scroll, since I am using view holder pattern and reusing the rows, the button2 that is being shown elsewhere in some rows in the list gets closed.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle it within the Adapter's getView callback. Something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
    Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         } 
    });


    return v;

}
```

Comment: hi, the above sample dowsnt answer my second question Q2: On scroll, since I am using view holder pattern and reusing the rows, the button2 that is being shown elsewhere in some rows in the list gets closed.

Comment: and i would have to declare button2 as final to use it in the listener. Is that what was meant ?